# Can I link against an OSX library file (.a) from Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, linker

Suppose I have a .a library file built in XCode (say for i386). For the sake of discussion let's assume it contains no OS calls (which would obviously fail). Is there some way I could link against it in a Windows environment?

To be more specific, suppose a static `Foo` method is defined in `bar.a`. Can I call it somehow from my code (say, C++ or C#)?

Comment: No - different object/library file formats, different ABIs - just recompile the OS X source for Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In very rare, carefully crafted cases it would be possible. For useful real-life applications: no, it won't work.

First, there's the linker format: OS X uses the [Mach-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) linker format while Windows uses the [Portable Executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) format (a modified COFF). 
There might be a way using GNU's `objcopy` (part of `binutils`) to convert one to another (it at least allows to copy sections from one linker format to another).

Apart from system calls, the major hurdle is that Windows and OS X use different [function call conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) (see the *List of x86 calling conventions* section).

For x86-64, they are incompatible: it's not possible for a "normal" Windows function to call a "normal" OS X function because they expect the arguments in different registers. With hand-crafted assembler and some tricks one might be able to generate a "universal" function, though.

With x86-32, chances to succeed are higher since arguments are passed on the stack for both systems. Returning values that are not 32-bit numbers would be difficult.

So one might succeed in writing a proof-of-concept function that can be linked and called in both operating systems (after converting the linker format). With common compilers, you might succeed in some rare cases on x86-32. But with x86-64 as produced by common compilers there is no way to compile it one system and link/call it on the other.